# how can I set content of request symfony?

Tags: symfony, request, symfony-forms

I generate manually request content of my form and want to set data like:

```
form[1][]=2&form[2][]=3&form[3][]=5&form[4][]=8&form[apply]=
```

The Symfony [Request](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php) object has an `getContent()` method, but hasn't `setContent()`.

How can I set content alternatively?

Comment: I guess you want to save you form result. I had the same problem. you can make that : $this->generateUrl('form_url', $request->query->all());

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution which is dirty but seems to work for me. Just reinitialize the request.

```
    $request->initialize(
        $request->query,
        $request->request,
        $request->attributes,
        $request->cookies,
        $request->files,
        $request->server,
        '<your-content>'
    );
```

Answer (score 6):

Symfony 4 > version:

```
$request->initialize(
    $request->query->all(),
    $request->request->all(),
    $request->attributes->all(),
    $request->cookies->all(),
    $request->files->all(),
    $request->server->all(),
    'your-content>'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is via `Request::create` method.

```
Request::create(
   '<uri>', 
   '<method>', 
   <parameters>, 
   <cookies>, 
   <files>, 
   <server>, 
   '<your-content>'
);
```

Source: [HTTP foundation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#simulating-a-request)

Answer (score 0):

Another dirty solution with usage of closures: https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.call.php

```php
$requestClosure = function() use ($decryptedJson) {
    $this->content = $decryptedJson;
    return $this;
};
$request = $requestClosure->call($request);
```

How this works:

- in closure the `$this` becomes the request itself so it's possible to call private `content`,
- calling `return $this` in closure returns the `$request` in context of which the call was made,